Help Needed with Conditional Probability Problem
In a production process, 10% of the units produced are defective. A defective unit is correctly classified as defective with a probability of $0.9$. A correct (non-defective) unit is incorrectly classified as defective with a probability of $0.15$.
Given this information, I need to compute the conditional probability that a unit is actually defective, given that it has been classified as defective.
I tried to use Bayes' Theorem to solve this problem: $P(D|C)=\frac{P(C|D)\cdot P(D)}{P(C)}$
D: The event that a unit is defective. C: The event that a unit is classified as defective.
$P(D)=0.1$ (probability that a unit is defective)
$P(C∣D)=0.9$ (probability that a defective unit is classified as defective)
$P(C∣D')=0.15$ (the probability that a non-defective unit is incorrectly classified as defective).
$P(D')=0.9$ (probability that a unit is not defective)
Could someone help clarify how to calculate $P(C)$?

Well, to build intuition, suppose that exactly $1000$ units were made.  How many of those are truly defective?  How many of them are non-defective but classified as defective anyway?  What would $P(C)$ be in this case?  (N.B.  I used $1000$ so that the various numbers come out as integers, but you could do it with $100$ if you think of these as percents instead of literal numbers of units).

Using the law of total probability, we have
$$
P(C) = P(C|D)P(D)+P(C|D')P(D') = 0.9\times0.1 + 0.15\times 0.9 = 0.225.
$$
We then have
$$
P(D|C)=\frac{P(C|D)P(D)}{P(C)} = \frac{0.9\times0.1}{0.225} = 0.4
$$

Your $P(C)$ is wrong.

Fixed. I was reading the probabilities from the list in the post instead of the word problem. $P(C|D')$ is supposed to be $0.15$ instead of $0.85$

Thanks! why P(C|D')=0.15?

" A correct (non-defective) unit is incorrectly classified as defective with a probability of 0.15." You then later state "$P(C∣D')=0.85$ (the probability that a non-defective unit is incorrectly classified as defective)." Not sure why you changed the number while the description of the event remained the same

Oh sorry, it's a typo

Let
$$R = p(\text{defective}) \times p(\text{true defective classification}).$$
Let
$$S = p(\text{non-defective}) \times p(\text{false  defective classification}).$$
Then, the desired computation is
$$\frac{R}{R + S} \tag1 $$
$$= \frac{0.1 \times 0.9}{(0.1 \times 0.9) + (0.9 \times 0.15)}.$$
Note that in (1) above, the denominator of $~R + S~$ represents the probability of somehow getting a classification of defective.

@lulu Good catch, thanks.  Answer edited.
